# Symfony2. Force a service to get instanced

Tags: php, symfony, containers

I'm working with symfony 2.8, I'm facing a situation where a service must be instanced even if it is not requested somewhere.

Why ? Because this Core service configure tagged services that are transfered by method calling into Core ( I did this in a compiler pass ).
And then, if I request one of these tagged services without request Core, it will not be configured and then be unusable.

Here is the compiler pass :

```
$coreDefinition = $container->findDefinition(
    'app.improvements.core'
);

$taggedAppliers = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('app.improvement.applier');

foreach ($taggedAppliers as $id => $tags) {
    $coreDefinition->addMethodCall(
        'registerApplier',
        [new Reference($id)]
    );
}

$taggedImprovements = $container->findTaggedServiceIds(
    'app.improvement'
);

// Only method found to initialize improvements.
foreach ($taggedImprovements as $id => $tags) {
    $coreDefinition->addMethodCall(
        'registerImprovement',
        [new Reference($id)]
    );
}
```

To sum up, the Appliers registers Improvement and Core registers Appliers. The core associate improvements with appliers because each improvement must be registered in a specific applier that the core stores.

The problem I that when I only request a Applier, its improvements are not registered into it because the core isn't instancied.

Thank you.

Comment: Can the service be made into a singleton?  If so you could instantiate it via a kernel event and have it suitably configured for use to be called later by any other objects.

Answer (score 3):

Design problems aside, the easiest way to instantiate a service is to use [an event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html). In your case you would listen for the `kernel.request` and pull your service from the container.

```
class RequestListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $event->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('service_id');
    }
}
```